# Change order of custom profile fields on Drupal register page

Tags: drupal, profile

I have created a custom profile in CiviCRM (**Administer > Custom Data and Screens > Profiles**) designated to be displayed on the Drupal registration page (see second screenshot), for users creating a new account. Initially, the CiviCRM profile was listed after the Drupal core elements: username, password, etc. But now the custom CiviCRM profile is displayed first.

How can I rearrange the order? I looked in Drupal blocks and do not see anything regarding these and I've tried assigning an order of "50" to no avail.

CiviCRM 4.7.27, Drupal 7

In the screenshot below, you can see that the "Tell us more" and darker text section is the CiviCRM custom profile and what follows it are the Drupal core elements that I want to be at the top.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ignore - I misread question and can't delete comment.

Comment: I am not sure what happened but this corrected itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `hook_form_alter` function in Drupal to accomplish this. In doing so, you can modify the weight of the items to appear *below* the existing form items.

```
function yourmod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $formID) {
  if (($formID == 'user_register_form')) {
    $form['civicrm-profile-register']['#weight'] = somevalue;
  }
}
```

Comment: What Christia is describing is not default Drupal behaviour is it? This code may indeed achieve what she wants, but I wonder what the underlying cause of this is. eg theme? another module?

Comment: It didn't used to be in this order either so something must have changed it, like you said. I'll have to see if I can identify what module or theme changes were made around the time that it changed. Changes to the weight has no affect.